# Unable to install xamarin forms apk from Gmail on android oreo as it says "There was a error parsing the package"

Tags: android, parsing, xamarin.forms, apk

I generated `Xamarin` forms release .apk with `minSdkVersion` "20" and selected Target Android version as **"Use Compile using SDK version"** from drop down.

I am able to successfully install and run my app on all the devices except android Oreo which has android version 8.

I have enabled "Install from unknown sources" in my device too.

Can anyone explain this issue?

Thanks

Comment: also i tried changing Target Android version to "Android 8.0", which also didn't help.

Comment: Have you tried in Release mode or debug mode?

Comment: I generated apk in release mode

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your compiling sdk version is Andorid 8.0 Oreo and also ensure that you sign in your app package with the proper signing key.